# Squid config for minimal setup to connect to bitbucket

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm trying to set up a very minimal squid config. I have one host machine (lets call it B) and to it attached is a machine (A). B is connected to the internet, A is not, but B and A are connected over an Ethernet cable. I have adapted [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116191/give-server-access-to-internet-via-client-connecting-by-ssh) for my purposes and would now like to configure the squid proxy on B to only allow A (local ip is `12.0.0.4`) to connect to one domain (`bitbucket.company_name.com`). My squid config is

```
#Mminimum configuration:

acl A src 12.0.0.4
acl BitBucket dstdomain bitbucket.company_name.com

http_access allow A
http_access allow BitBucket
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

negative_ttl 0
```

When I start the server and ssh into A via:

```
ssh -p 22022 -R 3129:localhost:3128 user@12.0.0.4
```

and then do

```
> git clone http://bitbucket.company_name.com/path/to/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo' ...
fatal: unable to access 'http://bitbucket.company_name.com/path/to/repo.git': Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT

>
> wget http://bitbucket.company_name.com
--2022-06-23 09:41:53--  http://bitbucket.company_name.com
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:3129... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2022-06-23 09:41:53 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

I tired reading on SE about the issue, mainly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599122/restrict-squid-access-to-only-one-site), but I cannot get it to work...

Comment: Do you need to authenticate before accessing `http://bitbucket.company_name.com/path/to/repo.git`? AFAIK the [CONNECT](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS#CONNECT_tunnel) is used to `tunnel` SSL/TLS based connections, not sure why a request to `http://bitbucket.company_name.com/` is tunneled through `CONNECT` method.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the logs to see if there is anything relevant:

```
/var/log/squid/
```

Bitbucket is based on java and it's a pain in the ass to get a reverse proxy running for it, even nginx or apache in my experience.

Comment: For what should I be watching out? As far as I can tell, nothing seems out of order...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the wrong port when connecting to the proxy from A.
The port you have configured Squid to listen to is 3128, but you are using port 3129 when connecting from A.
Try changing the port number when connecting to Squid from A:

```
ssh -p 22022 -R 3128:localhost:3128 user@12.0.0.4
```

Comment: This is not the issue. Take a look at [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116191/give-server-access-to-internet-via-client-connecting-by-ssh). The enviroment variables are set to send http requests on port 3129, which over the ssh tunnel end up at port 3128..

Comment: You are reversing the port 3129 to 3128 internally. That seem's fine. However, when you do ''git clone http://url/repo.git'' you do not specify a port... Therefore, it use 80... You need to specify the port here, in your case: 3129.  So it would be:  git clone http://git_url/repo.git:3129